# Unit testing ReactiveUI view models and commands

Tags: c#, reactiveui

I have a working view implemented using ReactiveUI and now I'm trying to write some unit tests for my view model, but my view model doesn't seem to work when used from the test.

Specifically, executing commands does not seem to trigger the subscribers. In this test below, I am invoking the AddPlayer command but the subscribed handler does not run:

```
public class NewGameViewModelTests
{
    private NewGameViewModel viewmodel;

    public NewGameViewModelTests()
    {
        viewmodel = new NewGameViewModel();            
    }

    [Fact]
    public void CanAddUpToSevenPlayers()
    {
        foreach(var i in Enumerable.Range(1, 7))
        {
            viewmodel.NewPlayerName = "Player" + i;
            viewmodel.AddPlayer.Execute(null);
            Assert.Equal(i, viewmodel.Players.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the view model I'm testing:

```
public class NewGameViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    public ReactiveList<string> Players { get; private set; }
    public ReactiveCommand<Object> AddPlayer { get; private set; }
    public ReactiveCommand<Object> RemovePlayer { get; private set; }
    public ReactiveCommand<Object> StartGame { get; private set; }
    public ReactiveCommand<Object> RandomizeOrder { get; private set; }


    string newPlayerName;
    public string NewPlayerName {
        get { return newPlayerName; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref newPlayerName, value); }
    }

    public NewGameViewModel()
    {
        Players = new ReactiveList<string> ();

        var canStart = this.Players.CountChanged.Select(count => count >= 3);
        StartGame = canStart.ToCommand();
        RandomizeOrder = canStart.ToCommand();

        RemovePlayer = ReactiveCommand.Create();
        AddPlayer = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Players.Count, x => x.NewPlayerName,
            (count, newPlayerName) => count < 7 && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newPlayerName) && !this.Players.Contains(newPlayerName))
            .ToCommand();

        RandomizeOrder.Subscribe(_ =>
        {
            using (Players.SuppressChangeNotifications())
            {
                var r = new Random();
                var newOrder = Players.OrderBy(x => r.NextDouble()).ToList();
                Players.Clear();
                Players.AddRange(newOrder);
            }
        });

        RemovePlayer.Subscribe(player =>
        {
            this.Players.Remove((string)player);
        });

        AddPlayer.Subscribe(_ =>
        {
            Players.Add(NewPlayerName.Trim());
            NewPlayerName = string.Empty;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code appears correct and I copied and pasted it onto my machine using RxUI 6.0.1 and the test passed.  The only change I made was converting the test to NUnit which only required renaming the attribute and changing the assertion syntax.  Something else must be going on here for you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

Doesn't seem to fail on my machine, using ReactiveUI master. Maybe something else is going on?

**Edit:** This is a bug in ReactiveUI with Xamarin.Forms, to work around it, add this to somewhere that runs at the start of your test runs:

```
RxApp.MainThreadScheduler = Scheduler.CurrentThread;
```

Comment: Ok so the problem appears to be with reactiveui-xamforms 6.0.3. When I remove the reference in my test project, the test starts passing. Is this a bug?

Comment: This is a bug in ReactiveUI, thanks for tracking it down

Comment: This is fixed in ReactiveUI 6.0.4, update and it should go away :)

Comment: This fixed my tests (ReactiveUI 9.19.5)